# Rock Paper Scissors, Random Class Variables

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a game of rock-paper-scissors. The user inputs for their choice. The prompt is:

```
System.out.print("Type R(ock), P(aper), or S(cissors): ");
```

So, r = rock, p = paper, and s = scissors. Similarly, the computer has to choose one (r, p, or s) using the Random class.

I know how to code it for a set range of numbers (I.e for choosing numbers between 1 and 20), but I have no clue how to set it up for a few specific letters, in this case r, p, and s.

Can anybody help explain it to me?

Edit:

Here is an example of basically what I am trying to print:

```
Type R(ock), P(aper) or S(cissors): **X**
Invalid answer. Re-type R, P or S: **y**
Invalid answer. Re-type R, P or S: **Z**
Invalid answer. Re-type R, P or S: **R**
You played rock. The computer played scissors.
```

And here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RPS {
   public static void main(String[] args); {
      Random piece = new Random();
      System.out.print("Type R(ock), P(aper) or S(cissors): ");
      int r = rock;
      int p = paper;
      int s = scissors;
      char types = {'r', 'p', 's'};
      while (!piece = types) {
         System.out.println("Invalid answer. Re-type R, P or S: ");
      }
   }

}
```

Now nobody get me wrong, I am not asking for anybody to give me the exact answers, but I am hoping for a point in the right direction.

Comment: Put them in a list / enum and retrieve by random index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to store whatever data you need in an array or list, this way every letter is going to be assigned an index number, which you can then use as a reference for generating a random number.

```
char[] types = {'r','p','s'};
System.out.println(types[new Random().nextInt(types.length)]);
```

You can find more information on arrays [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm)

**EDIT**
If you're not familiar with arrays you can use if statements for every case

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rock = 0, paper = 1, scissors = 2;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int random_try = rand.nextInt(3);

    if(random_try == 0){
      System.out.println("Random choice was Rock");
    }
    else if(random_try == 1){
      System.out.println("Random choice was Paper");
    }
    else if(random_try == 2){
      System.out.println("Random choice was Scissors");
    }

  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to make sure that I am understanding it correctly, that code will put the values as char values, then name the list as "types", then the third line calls them into the input?

Comment: @JonAkers to be precise it creates an array, every char value is then assigned an index number - 0, 1, 2. Then when you call the Random class it generates a random number between 0 and total number of elements within that array. So if the random number is 2 it takes the third element as counting begins at zero and outputs a letter.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there is a limit to the coding that I am allowed to use. We are working out of a textbook, and can only use what has been discussed so far. I don't believe that we have discussed arrays yet.
Also, have you seen the edits? I think I put them up right after you replied.

Comment: @JonAkers are you familiar with if or switch statements?

Comment: I have not used switched statements, but I have a fair understanding of "if" statements.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes it a lot easier for me to understand, and my teacher should accept this coding. I will have to edit it a bit, but you have been a great help.